# Is it possible to pass an std::string via Microsoft RPC?

Tags: visual-c++

I tried passing an std::string via RPC, but I got the following error:

> MIDL2025: syntax error: expecting a
>   type specification or a storage
>   specifer or a type qualifier near
>   "string"

Extract from code:

```
interface TestInterface
{
    unsigned int HelloUser([in] const string user);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a `BSTR`. Also, no `const`. By specifying the argument as `[in]`, it is already understood that the callee will not modify the string, and even if it did modify, it won't be marshaled back to the caller.

The [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6(v=VS.100).aspx) class will help with conversion. Note that `BSTR` is always based on `WCHAR`, which is 16-bit. Thus, use `std::wstring`.

Comment: You should also notice that you need to allocate the strings before passing them using SysAllocString().
Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx